# How do I skip a loop iteration based on the value of the last iteration performed?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am looping over a vector and I would like to know how to "skip" an iteration based on the last iteration.

For example: The first iteration will hit the 1, then the second will hit another 1, but I would like to skip that iteration IF the number is the same as the previous number.

Simple example:

```
vector <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4)

for (i in vector) {
print(i)
}
```

I do not want the iteration to print out "1" three times. I want it to skip to the next iteration until it reaches the 2. This needs to be dynamic as the real vector is much more complicated.

Vice versa, maybe I want to perform the next iteration, only if the iteration before it is the same.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `unique()`, here's another option that specifically looks at the previous value and could be more generalized:

```r
j <- ""
for (i in vector) {
  if (i == j) {
    j <- i
    next
  }
  print(i)
  j <- i
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. I was looking for this robust answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about iterating over the `unique` values of the vector?

```r
for (i in unique(vector)) {
  print(i)
}
# output
# [1] 1
# [1] 2
# [1] 3
# [1] 4
```

Comment: This would work as a simple answer, I need it to be a little more robust as I need certain things to occur if specific iterations happen.

Comment: If you want the search to explicitly check previous values of the vector, then look at @tims solution. Note also the efficiency issue even with this small vector of size 7.

Comment: `unique()` is definitely easier on the eyes and probably what I would default to... Performance would probably depend on the object type it's looking at has several different methods https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/6e70a157d92337d4da1a8ad35807110147ca65f8/src/library/base/R/duplicated.R#L96

Answer (score 1):

`rle` provides another approach. For your sample data, it will perform the same as `unique`, but in some other cases will differ (in ways that seem to better match your problem description):

```
vector <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5)
for(i in rle(vector)$values){
    print(i)
}

#output:

[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 1
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly look at the previous value

```
ind <- c(TRUE, vector[-length(vector)] != vector[-1])

print(vector[ind])

# or
for (i in which(ind)){
  vector[i]
 }
```